# How to capture stderr to a variable if there is an error executing the script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, stderr, aws-cli

I am executing some API calls in a bash script. In this case if the API call succeeds, then a `json` file is returned, if it fails a `stderr` is returned. I would like to capture the `stderr` and parse it on a fail. After reviewing a lot of answers on SO I found no combination so far that works.

For example, I have added the below rule already, so when I run:

```
myCmd=("aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-999aa999 --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 ")
${myCmd[@]} > myJson.file

#check if success
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ] 
then
   # PARSE STDERR
fi
```

The success check returns 255 and stderr returns below. So now I would like to parse the message to check if it is a general error or a duplicate:

> A client error (InvalidPermission.Duplicate) occurred when calling the
>   AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: the specified rule "peer:
>   0.0.0.0/0, TCP, from port: 80, to port: 80, ALLOW" already exists

Comment: To capture the stderr you should use `${myCmd[@]} > myJson.file 2> myJson.err` and use the `myJson.err` in the body of `then` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myCmd=("aws --profile myProfile --region eu-west-1 ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-999aa999 --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 ")

if "${myCmd[@]}" > myJson.file 2> error.file; then
   echo ok
else
    err="$(cat error.file)"
    # do domething with $err
fi
```

Comment: giving this as correct answer as it runs the cmd and parses the pass/fail into if/else in one line so I don't need to do any further testing.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
message=$(${myCmd[@]} 2>&1 >myJson.file)
```

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to where `stdout` is connected, which is the pipe used for the command substitution. Since redirections are processed from left to right, this happens before `stdout` is redirected to the file.

You can then parse the error message in `$message`.

Comment: thanks @Barmar appreciate the speedy reply, this does work but I must then do an additional step to test as per my original code compared to sputnick's answer that makes the entire block a little simpler

Comment: You can do the same thing with this: `if message=$(...)`.